# SQL Max(something,0) type solution

Tags: sql, sum, max

I would like to do the following:

SELECT sum(max(field-10,000,0)) from TABLE

as in, I want to have field-10,000 summed up, but if field-10,000 < 0 then I want it to add 0.

any suggestions?

Karl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ANSI` syntax (supported by `SQL Server`, `Oracle`, `MySQL` and `PostgreSQL`):

```
SELECT  SUM(CASE WHEN FIELD < 10000 THEN 0 ELSE FIELD - 10000 END)
FROM    mytable
```

Using `GREATEST` (not supported by `SQL Server`):

```
SELECT  SUM(GREATEST(field - 10000, 0))
FROM    mytable
```